# How do I move Phaser.Game to the center of a browser?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

[image]

I'm new to JS/phaser and just create a `Phaser.Game` with

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(600, 490);
```

The game is created top left but I would like to have it placed in the center of a browser.

I checked the [API](https://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Game.html) and nothing looks relevant:

```
new Game(width, height, renderer, parent, state, transparent, antialias, physicsConfig)
```

Could someone tell me how do I do so?

Comment: Probably something along the lines of `<canvas style="margin:auto;"></canvas>`.  It's a CSS issue, not really a Phaser issue.

Comment: have you checked [this](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/1609-centering-canvas/). Does it help?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Ahh! It helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this link](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/1609-centering-canvas/) provided by @FedericoklezCulloca.

add

```
game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
game.scale.refresh();
```

to function `update` and the `Phaser.Game` will be in the middle.

Comment: The `update` event will be called for every frame. I would add it to `preload` or `create` function, because you only need to set the scaling once.

Answer (score 5):

**Using Laravel 8 and phaser@3.24.1**

The solution found [here](https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/1609-centering-canvas/?do=findComment&comment=11418) worked for me. The other answers provided in this thread did not (but did point me in the correct direction).

```
canvas {
display : block;   
margin : auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example the game will be centered but the logo is at 0,0

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(640, 480, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create });

        function preload() {

            game.load.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
            game.load.image('logo', 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/photonstorm/phaser-examples/master/examples/assets/sprites/phaser2.png');

        }

        function create() {
            game.scale.scaleMode = Phaser.ScaleManager.SHOW_ALL;
            game.scale.pageAlignHorizontally = true;
            game.scale.pageAlignVertically = true;
            var logo = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'logo');

        }
```

```css
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser-ce/2.11.0/phaser.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use game config options to work with size and scale

```
const gameConfig: Phaser.Types.Core.GameConfig = {
    parent: 'game',
    scale: {
        mode: Phaser.Scale.RESIZE, // you can find another types in Phaser.Scale.ScaleModeType: RESIZE | FIT | ENVELOP ...
        autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
    },
    ...yourRest
}
```

Also I recommend to add css to your :

```
#id {
  width: 100vw; // you can skip it
  height: 100vh; // you can skip it
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  canvas {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
  }
}
```